# Aggregating User's Tasks in SharePoint 2013

Tags: tasks, user, task-list, aggregation

I have been scouring the internet for that past several weeks trying to come up with a solution, but I am lost.

I need a web part that can do two things:

1. Display all incomplete tasks for a specific user. (The tasks are located across various subsites in one site collection).
2. Display the corresponding due date for each task.

If we could get a checkbox on there to mark a task as complete, that would be great as well. We are using SharePoint 2013.

As a side note, I tried to use a content query to do this, but I could not get it to show the due date.

Any insight would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is what the Work Management Service is for. On the User Profile Tasks page it accumulates the tasks from SharePoint, Project Server Sites and Exchange 2013 (if you have that and it's connected).

Warning though, it has been removed from SharePoint 2016 and Office 365.

Reference: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12525.sharepoint-2013-work-management-service-application.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For me you have to use an SPSiteDataQuery to perform operation across multiple webs in the same site collection.
Here is doc from msdn with working example :
[MSDN Artcile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx)